# How to add a package logo picture (which has finished design & saved as png) in README at Github

Tags: r, github, package

I add `<img src="man/figure/logo.png" align="right" height="138.5"/>` in README.md

And also put logo.png into that file. (ps. I design the logo using IDesign)

**However, the logo does not shows up in my README file at Github**

I wonder whether if my size of logo is too big? (105kb)

I tried to change picture size in IDesign through change the parameter of quality & Resoulution, however if I change it too small, it would be hard to recognise the pattern on the logo.

Or there is something else I need to fix

[image]

Comment: `figure` or `figures`?

Comment: So smart bro! Fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use in below way for my avatar image

```
![Vipul Avatar](./avatar.png "I'm Vipul")

![Vipul Avatar](https://github.com/vipulkumarsviit/randomcodes/blob/master/avatar.png "I'm Vipul")
```

in the same way, you can also use

```
![Alt Text for your logo](./man/figure/logo.png "My Logo")

![Alt Text for your logo](https://github.com/vipulkumarsviit/randomcodes/blob/master/man/figure/logo.png "My Logo")
```

Hope I was able to solve your problem